# AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'node'

Tags: graphql, saleor

I want to add new functionality product QA in Saleor. I start a new app "QA"  and create a model to store this info such as product info, staff user, QA status, and QA date.
I create grqaphql API to add data but when I try to get product info it reflects "AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'node'"

Here is my model

```
class QA (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qa_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True , blank=True)
    qa_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default="Pending")
    qa_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True , blank=True)
```

Here is my Graphql Mutation

```
class QAType(CountableDjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = [graphene.relay.Node]
        model = QA
        fields="__all__"

    
class ProductQAInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    product = graphene.ID(description="Product ID.", required=True)
    qa_by = graphene.ID(description="Staff User ID.", required=True)
    qa_status = graphene.String(description="QA Status if changed .")
    qa_date = graphene.String(description="QA Date .")


class CreateProductQA(ModelMutation):

    class Arguments:
        input = ProductQAInput(
         description="Fields required"
        )
   
    class Meta:
        description = " QA."
        model = QA
        error_type_class = QAError
        error_type_field = "qa_errors"

    @classmethod
    def perform_mutation(cls, _root, info, **data):
        response = super().perform_mutation(_root, info, **data)
        return response
```

```
mutation{
  createProductQA(input:{product:"UHJvZHVjdDo2MQ==", qaBy:"VXNlcjo5NjM="}){
    qA{
      id
      product{
        id
        name
      }
      qaBy{
        id
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```